# How to generate 95%CI for zero-hurdle model in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am trying to generate 95% CIs for predictors in both the count and hurdle portions of my zero hurdle model.

Using the `'pscl'` package, my code looks like this:

```
m1 <- hurdle(EDE_OBE_epi_eot ~ WCST_T2_bl + BDI_total_bl + EDE_OBE_epi_bl + THERAPY + KSADS_BN_Duration_bl + KSADS_Comor_bl, data = datawide, dist = "negbin")
```

And output looks like this:

```
Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8232 -0.5234 -0.3563 -0.1536  3.2578 

Count model coefficients (truncated negbin with log link):
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)           1.433271   1.977618   0.725   0.4686  
WCST_T2_bl           -0.011161   0.026940  -0.414   0.6787  
BDI_total_bl         -0.008226   0.030970  -0.266   0.7905  
EDE_OBE_epi_bl        0.037321   0.020455   1.825   0.0681 .
THERAPY               0.654449   0.523804   1.249   0.2115  
KSADS_BN_Duration_bl -0.011483   0.017437  -0.659   0.5102  
KSADS_Comor_bl        0.288576   0.716143   0.403   0.6870  
Log(theta)            0.985550   0.727385   1.355   0.1754  
Zero hurdle model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)          -5.23248    2.90030  -1.804   0.0712 .
WCST_T2_bl            0.03650    0.03763   0.970   0.3322  
BDI_total_bl          0.08452    0.04626   1.827   0.0677 .
EDE_OBE_epi_bl        0.04502    0.02904   1.550   0.1210  
THERAPY               0.22977    0.73298   0.313   0.7539  
KSADS_BN_Duration_bl  0.01177    0.01707   0.689   0.4906  
KSADS_Comor_bl       -1.49946    1.01557  -1.476   0.1398  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta: count = 2.6793
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 28 
Log-likelihood: -63.8 on 15 Df
```

Let's say, for example, I am interested in the 95%CI for `BDI_total_bl` for both the count and hurdle output. How can I get this? Thanks -

Comment: `coef(m1)` and `confint(m1)` should give you the point estimate and 95% ci of the model parameters, respectively